# Python Patch not resetting between tests

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a unit test class that tests the same method twice - once with happy path and once with a failure. If I run both tests individually then they pass, but if I run them together then the patch `return_value` from the first test is also applied to the second, and so one test will fail. What am I missing here?

```py
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from unittest.mock import Mock


class MainTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_happy_path(self):
        with mock.patch('google.cloud.bigquery.Client') as bq_patch:
            bq_patch().insert_rows_json.return_value = None
            import main
            data = {'trigger': 'testval'}
            req = Mock(get_json=Mock(return_value=data), args=data)
            assert 200 == main.http_to_bq(req)
            bq_patch.reset_mock()
            req.reset_mock()

    def test_bigquery_error(self):
        with mock.patch('google.cloud.bigquery.Client') as bq_patch:
            bq_patch().insert_rows_json.return_value = 'BigQuery connection error found'
            import main
            data = {'trigger': 'testval'}
            req = Mock(get_json=Mock(return_value=data), args=data)
            assert 500 == main.http_to_bq(req)
            req.reset_mock()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was concentrating on the patches when actually the problem was with `import main`. The patch is applied when `main` is imported for the first time, and subsequent `import main` calls do nothing. I imported:

```py
from importlib import reload
```

and replaced both instances of

```py
import main
```

with

```py
import main
reload(main)
```

That allows `main` to be re-patched with the latest patch.

Comment: Assuming you are importing the bigquery client in `main`, you should instead patch something like `patch('main.Client')` -that is, patch where you are using the module, not the original place.